# How to fix Qt requires a C++17 compiler?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, conan

I use conan-installed Qt-6.2.2.
I created Qt Widgets Project in VS-2019, switched language to `std:c++17`, added `/Zc:__cplusplus` to additional options.

Since this is conan-installed QT, it don't have `Qt.props`, so I manually created one which includes the props file generated by `conan install`.

[image]

But it still complains:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C1189   #error:  "Qt requires a C++17 compiler, and a suitable
> value for __cplusplus. On MSVC, you must pass the /Zc:__cplusplus
> option to the
> compiler."    QtWidgetsApplication2   D:.conan\579957\1\include\QtCore\qglobal.h 94

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the options `-Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -permissive- -Zc:__cplusplus -Zc:externConstexpr -utf-8 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458`.

I had the same issue with Qt6.2.0 and Qt-VS-Tools2.7.2 in VS2019.

Setting only `/Zc:__cplusplus` as the error message proposes did not solve it,
but setting the options above worked for me.
(I copied them from an old project where they were autogenerated)

Comment: I am using the same version and finally, that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue in VS2019 with **qt-vsaddin-msvc2019-2.5.2-rev.01**. I had to install **qt-vsaddin-msvc2019-2.8.1**, switch the "C++ Language Standard" to std:c++17 and add `/Zc:__cplusplus` to additional options.

Comment: Both these changes were necessary and sufficient to solve the problem for me with Qt version 6.5.2 and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.30.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, Changing "Properties->General-> C++ Language standard" to $(Qt_STDCPP_) solved the problem form me.