# How to fix "Qt requires a C++17 compiler" error?

Tags: macos, qt, gcc, compiler-errors, cgal

I installed with `brew` the CGAL C++ library.
After doing `cmake .` in the [first basic example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html#usage_introduction) , I do `make` and I got a sequence of errors, the first one and most important is:

```
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:96:6: error: "Qt requires a C++17 compiler"
#    error "Qt requires a C++17 compiler"
     ^
```

which means that I need a way to tell Qt to use a C++17 compiler. How can I fix this? I'm an engineer, and I've never faced a similar issue before. There have been similar questions before (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70373606/how-to-fix-qt-requires-a-c17-compiler)) but they're about Windows.

I'm using a MacOS BigSur, 11.6.2. and `gcc --version` returns

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42834844/1918193

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you will need to tell cmake to activate c++17 support in the compiler commands it generates. By default, Apple clang was chosen, and that comes with an earlier default std support.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++17" .
```

If for whatever reason you intended to compile with the `gcc` wrapper or some other compiler, you can let cmake know:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++17" .
```

Answer (score 11):

I did run `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++17" .` to fix this but it didn't help. After spending a day trying to solve this issue, I solved it by removing qt (`brew uninstall qt`). I had installed both `qt` and `qt@5` and I think CMake was getting confused and picking up some files from qt, and others from qt@5. Hope this help someone.

Comment: Exactly. Brew now installs Qt 6 by default instead of 5. Thank you

Comment: I had some dependencies installed that meant `brew uninstall qt` didn't want to run. In this case, using `brew unlink qt` solved it for me.