# Qt #error :Qt requires a C++17 compiler, and a suitable value for __cplusplus

Tags: visual-studio, qt

My versions: Visual Studio Community 2022 and Qt 6.3.2.

When I compile my project, the error happens:
Qt requires a C++17 compiler, and a suitable value for __cplusplus. On MSVC, you must pass the /Zc:__cplusplus option to the compiler.

I tried according to the tip and still it does not work.

Besides, the answer in [How to fix Qt requires a C++17 compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70373606/how-to-fix-qt-requires-a-c17-compiler) does not work either.

Comment: As well as the `/Zc` flag, you also need to explicitly set the C++ standard for your project to C++17 or later. IIRC, the default for VS2022 is C++14.

Comment: I chose the C++ 17 also. But both of the adding /Zc:__cplusplus and the set of C++17 do not work.